# c#.net sendmail relay error

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server

I've recently rewritten some code form VB.net to C#.net.
The VB code still sends mail but with the C# code I get a "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay"-error.

Configuration is the same and I am testing with IIS 7.5 on a Windows 2008 R2 machine, the Exchange-server I am sending from is running on another server I don't have access to. The recipient is a mailaccount on a server hosted by 1&1 Germany.

The "old but working" VB.NET Code:

```
Private Sub sendemail(mailadresse As String, betreff As String, nachricht As String)

    Dim plainnachricht As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(nachricht, Nothing, "text/plain")
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage() With {.From = New MailAddress("from@exchange.de", "Sender")}
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(mailadresse, "Recipient"))
        mail.Subject = betreff
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainnachricht)
        mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        Dim smtpclient As New SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 25) With {.UseDefaultCredentials = False, .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "password"), .EnableSsl = False, .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network}
        smtpclient.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Infolbl.Text = "Mail not send"
    End Try
```

And the new C#.NET Code:

```
    private void sendemail(string mailadresse, string betreff, string nachricht)
    {
        AlternateView plainnachricht = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(nachricht, null, "text/plain");
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("from@exchange.de", "Sender"), new MailAddress(mailadresse, "Recipient"));
            mail.Subject = betreff;
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainnachricht);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 25))
            {
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Infolbl.Text = "Mail not send";
        }
    }
```

Using a different mail address on the exchange server as recipient the mail gets send and arrives. I've also tried a Gmail address which gets the same error with the C# code. VB always works.

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Is the sending box the same in both instances? If not, your c# box might not have permission to send email.

Comment: Yes it is the same mailbox

Comment: The username might need a domain specified.  In VB.NET "DOMAIN\User" would be automatically escaped but in c# you need to do this yourself, eg, "DOMAIN\\user".

Comment: But I am able to send mail to another exchange mail account, just not to an outside mail address. So I am getting a connection to exchange without a domain specified.

Comment: Depending on your server settings, you are permitted internal relay without authentication, but external relay would be denied unless you are authenticated.  Without checking the server settings or logs it would be difficult to determine what exactly the settings or errors are.  The most obvious error is the missing escape character - If this does not work then you may need to talk to your exchange admin for assistance.

Comment: After trying a couple of different combinations with the domain - networkcredetial(user, password, domain) or domain\user - I realized there was a typo in the password. Thanks for helping me anyways. For me it works without having to add the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was password typo. In my case the exchange server only needed the username, no domain.